# Maven project running correctly from eclipse but not command line

Tags: java, maven

I have a java project with a package called main and a Main class. It runs from eclipse but it doesn't work when I try this from command line in the pom.xml directory:

```
mvn compile
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=main.Main
```

I get a ClassNotFoundException on the mvn exec:java command, even though this is the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

is the package name for your class Main called main?

The following example will create a basic project, compile it, and execute the App class

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false
cd my-app/
mvn compile
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.App"
```

Comment: the package is called main. I tried these commands and got this error on the first one: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project my-app: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom' -> [Help 1]